# Unable to get constant button look with jQuery and CodeIgniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I use CodeIgniter to setup the following :

-a button. A click links to a brand new page
-another button, that submit the form it is linked to

The code is a follows :

```
<script language="javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("input:submit, a" ).button();
      return false;
  });
</script>

<!-- Here I setup the form -->
<?php echo anchor('/admin/add/', 'Add'); ?>
<?php echo form_submit('Delete', 'Delete')?>
<!-- Here I add text fields etc... -->
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

My problem is that the  anchor button is slightly bigger than the submit one.

Did I mess something ? The CSS is now modified anywhere else...

Thanks !

Comment: What's your .button() do? I've never seen that before?

Comment: @MattMoore: Please check here http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/. I guess it setups the button UI style stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a CSS issue. Try troubleshooting by removing all stylesheets from your template except for the jQuery UI stylesheet. Also try using a CSS reset like this one http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
This should remove the padding and font-size difference between elements.
If your browser has an inspector (like Firefox's Firebug) try inspecting your a tag and submit button to see what stylesheet the differences in styles are coming from.

Comment: Actually, if you watch carrefully http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/, you'll notice that the submit button is slightly smaller than other buttons... I'm wondering whether anything can actually be done here...I'll try your suggestion asap, will keep you posted !

Comment: I found this ticket : http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5254. It looks like the JQuery team is not willing to fix this issue. To them, having two buttons side to side is not a typical use case... I will not comment that any further...